# Using composition to get ceiling of a division

Tags: haskell, currying, function-composition

I'm learning haskell, and I'm trying to rewrite a function using composition only

Here's the function I'm trying to refactor:

```hs
ceilingDiv a b = ceiling (a / b)
```

So far I managed to make it work using curry and uncurry but it feels dirty:

```hs
ceilingDiv = curry $ ceiling . uncurry (/)
```

Is there any way to do this more cleanly? I was thinking `ceiling . div`, but it doesn't work because `(/)` returns a function and ceiling takes a Double as its argument.

Comment: I hope you want to do this just to do some Haskell practice and not because you genuinely think the latter point-free refactoring is better than the original :-). By all means, feel free to tinker and experiment for the sake of learning, but understand that sometimes using simple, short, down-to-earth code is the right way, and the "clever" variants are obfuscation. BTW, on positive integral variables sometimes ``(a+b-1) `div` b`` can be more efficient than passing through floating point values.

Comment: Yep, that was only for learning purposes. Thanks for the tip on using div instead of (/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compositions with multiple arguments are usually best just left in point-ful form. None of the alternatives is as clean and clear. Do make use of composition- and grouping operators, but don't golf away arguments just for the sake of it.

```
ceilingDiv a b = ceiling $ a/b
```

What you can certainly do is eta-reduce the `b` argument

```
ceilingDiv a = ceiling . (a/)
```

but I'd leave it at that. Even that is IMO less clean than the original 2-argument form, because the division operator needs to be sectioned.

When directly passing compositions to a higher-order function then it can make sense to aim a bit more agressively point-free, to avoid lambda bindings. The [`composition` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.2.2/docs/Data-Composition.html#v:.:) has a whole bunch of operators for composing with more arguments. In this case, you could use the indeed quite concise

```
ceilingDiv = ceiling .: (/)
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I had a hunch that it was best left in point-ful form, but the goal of the exercise was to practice function composition. The composition package looks interesting, even if only for exploratory/learning purposes. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 7):

There's a fun site called https://pointfree.io - it provides a solution to your problem like this: `ceilingDiv = (ceiling .) . (/)`. It looks ugly because point-free composition with multiple arguments is a pain. Sometimes it's achieved by using `.` [sections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) like here, sometimes by using an [Applicative](https://wiki.haskell.org/Applicative_functor) instance of functions and the `<*>` operator.

I think your solution with curry-uncurry is nice. It deals with passing multiple arguments by wrapping them into one tuple.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting https://pointfree.io/. I have a feeling this will be useful for future shenanigans!